Matlab crashes after using vl_sift function with MSER-detected keypoints
I'm trying to use vlfeat to calculate MSER features and then input them as keypoints to perform SIFT description. My issue is, no matter how many keypoints, matlab crashes, I can't really understand why and I'm too new in this field to know more, any ideas?
% Clear workspace and initialize
clear;
clc;
close all;

% Step 1: Load the image
img = imread('footwear.jpg'); % Replace with your image file name
if size(img, 3) == 3
    grayImg = rgb2gray(img); % Convert to grayscale if it's an RGB image
else
    grayImg = img;
end

% Step 2: Perform MSER detection
mserRegions = detectMSERFeatures(grayImg);

% Extract MSER locations and scales
mserLocations = mserRegions.Location;
mserScales = mserRegions.Axes; % Major and minor axes of MSER ellipses

% Compute approximate scales using the geometric mean of axes
numRegions = size(mserLocations, 1);
scales = sqrt(prod(mserScales, 2)); % Geometric mean of axes
orientations = zeros(numRegions, 1); % Default orientation (set to 0)

% Limit the number of keypoints (to prevent excessive memory usage)
maxKeypoints = min(500, numRegions); % Use at most 500 keypoints
mserLocations = mserLocations(1:maxKeypoints, :);
scales = scales(1:maxKeypoints);
orientations = orientations(1:maxKeypoints);

% Construct frames matrix for VLFeat
frames = [mserLocations(:, 1)'; mserLocations(:, 2)'; scales'; orientations'];

% Step 3: Set up VLFeat
run('C:\Users\user\Desktop\ERGASIA\vlfeat-0.9.21\toolbox\vl_setup'); % Replace with your VLFeat path

% Step 4: Compute SIFT descriptors using VLFeat
try
    [~, descriptors] = vl_sift(single(grayImg), 'frames', frames);
catch ME
    fprintf('Error during SIFT computation: %s\n', ME.message);
    return;
end

% Step 5: Visualize MSER regions and SIFT keypoints
figure;
imshow(grayImg);
hold on;

% Plot MSER regions
plot(mserRegions, 'showPixelList', false, 'showEllipses', true);

% Plot SIFT keypoints
vl_plotframe(frames);

title('MSER Regions and SIFT Keypoints');
hold off;

% Display some statistics
fprintf('Number of MSER Regions Detected: %d\n', numRegions);
fprintf('Number of Keypoints Used: %d\n', maxKeypoints);
fprintf('Size of Descriptors: [%d x %d]\n', size(descriptors));


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
